# What's the difference between "balancing" and "load-balancing" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

What's the difference between [balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/balancing) and [load-balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing) tags?

Should they be merged and made synonyms?

Answer (score 4):

Yep, someone please synonym [balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/balancing) to [load-balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/load-balancing)

Comment: There's a few synonyms that need to be made, but first thing we need to do is clean up the [balance] tag to get rid of all the stray [load] tags. This should be done soon, I noticed a few people have been pitching in to get it done.